# automate openFileDialog process in c#

Tags: c#

I have tried this code it would open the file dialog  to the correct location and there is only one xml file which needs to selected ( where i need to select it and click on open ) instead of selecting the file and click open to process the file is there any way to disable the open  button on open file dialog. Here my xml file changes everyday. i have given *.xml but gives me a error Illegal characters in path.. my file format is this.

lborough vehicles_in 2014-06-05.xml == this changes everyday according to date.

Without clicking on open how to select the file.

```
OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
dialog.Filter = "XML Files (*.xml)|*.xml";
string initPath = Path.GetFullPath("C:/Users/IT-Administrator/Desktop/LUVS/");
dialog.InitialDirectory = Path.GetFullPath(initPath);
tblVehicles = new DataTable();
dv = new DataView(tblVehicles);

if (dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    if (dialog.FileName.Length > 0)
    {
        //Load Schema and Vehicle_In XML file
        tblVehicles.ReadXmlSchema(Path.Combine(applicationFolder, "vehicles_in.xsd"));
        tblVehicles.ReadXml(dialog.FileName);

        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = tblVehicles;
        this.dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        this.dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;
```

****Update****
I have tried this can you tell me how to open the file from Directory.get files at runtime

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\IT-Administrator\Desktop\LUVS/", "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories); 
FileStream stream = File.Open(@"C:\Users\IT-Administrator\Desktop\LUVS*.xml", 
FileMode.Open); 
tblVehicles = new DataTable(); 
dv = new DataView(tblVehicles); 
tblVehicles.ReadXmlSchema(Path.Combine(applicationFolder, "vehicles_in.xsd")); 
tblVehicles.ReadXml(stream);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your attempted solution at the end doesn't quite get it:

```
/* Gives you an array of file names */
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\IT-Administrator\Desktop\LUVS/", "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories); 

FileStream stream = File.Open(@"C:\Users\IT-Administrator\Desktop\LUVS*.xml", 
FileMode.Open);
```

You aren't using the array, but instead just trying to open a wildcard path; You can't do that. `File.Open` only accepts a single file path.

Instead, try something more like this:

```
/* Gives you an array of file names */
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\IT-Administrator\Desktop\LUVS/", "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories); 

// Work with each file individually
foreach(var filePath in filePaths)
{
    using(FileStream stream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        tblVehicles = new DataTable(); 
        dv = new DataView(tblVehicles); 
        tblVehicles.ReadXmlSchema(Path.Combine(applicationFolder, "vehicles_in.xsd")); 
        tblVehicles.ReadXml(stream);
        // Do whatever you need to do with the data from this one file, then move on....
     {
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason that you can't use [Directory.GetFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/07wt70x2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get all files in a directory and use [File.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the file? Why do you want to do this with a FileDialog, if you don't want the FileDialog?

Update:

```
 //Load Schema and Vehicle_In XML file
 tblVehicles.ReadXmlSchema(Path.Combine(applicationFolder, "vehicles_in.xsd"));

 // Get all XML files from the files directory
 string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"files\", "*.xml", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

 // Read the first XML file in the files directory
 tblVehicles.ReadXml(filePaths[0]);
```

Is this what you asked for?

Comment: Good point, but "This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be a comment."

Comment: how is it possible to select the  xml file at runtime as there  will be only one file in the directory

Comment: Hi Erwin, I have updated the query can you suggest me how to open files at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SendKeys()` but it's clunky, and if the user moves focus elsewhere you might end up sending the keystrokes to the wrong window.

`openFileDialog` isn't very customizable, so you might want to consider using `openFolderDialog` and append the known filename to the user selected directory.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to select your file and inmediately work with it, you want a button behaviour. Best way here is to make your own UserControl showing files existing on your directory.
1. Get files from directory
2. Show dialog with buttons, every buttons asociated to its file.
3. On button click, close dialog and pass file to your method.